# Iron router data findOne returning undefined

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a `streams` publication and subscription setup but for some reason if I do the following in my route the view gets no data:

```
Router.route '/seasons/:season/episodes/:episode',
    name: 'episode'
    action: ->
        @render(
            'episode',
            data: ->
                Streams.findOne({season: @params.season, episode: @params.episode})
        )
```

If I log the params they are there as expected, and doing a `findOne` manually either via the db or the browser console returns the data as expected.

If I remove the params so it just does `Streams.findOne()` the data returns the first `stream` from the database and the view has access to it as expected. I'm really not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wait on your streams publication before trying to access the data : Pub/Sub mechanism in Meteor is asynchronous, when you subscribe to some data, you don't instantly get it back in the browser because of the underlying client/server latency.

Try reorganizing your code as follow :

```
Router.route '/seasons/:season/episodes/:episode',
  name: 'episode'
  template: 'episode'
  data: ->
    Streams.findOne({season: @params.season, episode: @params.episode})
  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'streams', @params.season, @params.episode
```

Comment: Now I get this error `Exception from sub 6hdDJSYJHkEpP5yS3 Error: Did not check() all arguments during publisher 'episodes'`

The data I'm returning has changed slightly to return an object like so: `{ episode: Episodes.findOne({season: 3, episode: 1}), games: Games.find({season: 3, episode: 1})}`.

I tried waiting on both following this https://coderwall.com/p/yhpn9a/waiton-and-multiple-subscriptions-in-iron-router but still get the error.

Comment: I figured it out the params were being returned as strings but the data in mongo I was doing the find on is numbers, I simply added: `parseInt(@params.season, 10)`. 

Does this sound like a reasonable mistake to make or am I missing something else?